# How to run 'node' and 'npm' commands outside of the nodejs folder that was downloaded from nodejs.org

Tags: node.js, windows, cmd, command

So, I installed node.js in a computer and saved the nodejs folder in program files folder.

However, I am not able to run an node or npm command in cmd unless the path I am in is either Program Files or in Program Files. How do I use the commands everywhere?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need to add the directory to your Path environment variable.
Usually, nodejs does this for you during the installation but if you forgot to select that option, you can always add it manually:

1. Open the Start menu in Windows, type "env" and select "Edit the system environment variables", you end up on the "Advanced" tab of the System properties dialog. On this tab, you can see four buttons, the last of which says "Environment variables"
2. Click that button to open the environment variables dialog, in which you will see two panels, the upper being the variables for your current user, the lower one being the system-wide variables.
3. In both panels, you can find a variable named "Path". Select the one you want to edit (user-wide or system-wide) and click on "Edit".
4. In the Edit dialogue, you see a list of Windows paths currently in the "Path" variable. You'll want to click on "New", which creates a new entry and then click on "Find..." to open a window to let you select a folder on your system. There, find and select the folder you installed nodejs to, that is, the folder containing the "node.exe" executable as well as the "npm" and "npx" scripts.
5. Save everything, fire up a CMD or PowerShell and test by entering `node --version`

Alternatively, just re-install node and during the installation, watch out for a checkbox say something the likes of "Add installation folder to %PATH%".

Comment: Thanks! It works like a charm. I think I did this the first time I installed nodejs, but forgot all about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Windows.

From www.howtogeek.com:

> The Windows System PATH tells your PC where it can find specific directories that contain executable files. ipconfig.exe, for example, is found in the C:\Windows\System32 directory, which is a part of the system PATH by default. When you type ipconfig into a Command Prompt, Windows doesn’t need to know where that EXE is–it’ll check all the folders in its PATH until it finds the right one.

So we have to add the path of the nodejs installation folder(which contains node.exe and npm.exe files) in the path environment variable.

So windows button on keyboard and search edit the system environment variables.

Open it and then in the System Variables settings search Path

Click edit and then insert in a new line:

C:\Program Files\nodejs\

Or where you have installed node.

(if you go in this dir you see the npm.cmd and node.exe files).

Restart.

Now try npm or node commands on cmd everywhere you want.